# Integral of a complex function over a circle

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I've got the problem. I was to compute:

$\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1- cos(n\phi)}{1 - cos(\phi)} d\phi$

using analytic functions methods. My attempt: I came to this:

On a unit circle, we have $z= e^{i\phi}$, where $\phi \in [0, 2\pi)$. Then, we obtain $log(z) = i \phi \Rightarrow dz = ie^{log(z)} d\phi = iz d\phi \Rightarrow d\phi = \frac{1}{iz} dz$.

So my integral is equal to (C is a unit circle):

$\int_C \frac{1}{iz} \frac{1- cos(n\frac{log,z}{i})}{1 - cos(\frac{logz}{i})} dz =  \int_C \frac{1}{iz} \frac{1- \frac{e^{nlogz} + e^{-nlogz}}{2}}{1 - \frac{e^{logz} + e^{-logz}}{2}} dz = \int_C \frac{1}{iz} \frac{1- \frac{z^n +z^{-n} }{2}}{1 - \frac{z + z^{-1}}{2}} dz = \int_C \frac{z^{-n}(z^n -1)^2}{i(z-1)^2} dz$

Here I got stuck. How to compute $\int_C \frac{z^{-n}(z^n -1)^2}{i(z-1)^2} dz$? Can you show me? I will be grateful.

Comment: But $1$ isn't in the interior of the disk bounded by circle $C$?

Comment: Yeah, I just realized :). I'll post something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cauchy formula you seek is of the form

$$f^{(n-1)}(0) = \frac{(n-1)!}{2 \pi i} \oint_{|z|=1} dz \frac{f(z)}{z^n}$$

where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  So your integral looks like, from @Omnomnomnom,

$$-i \oint_{|z|=1} dz \frac{(1+z+z^2+\cdots+z^{n-1})^2}{z^n}$$

which is then equal to

$$\frac{2 \pi}{(n-1)!}  \left [\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left (1+z+z^2+\cdots+z^{n-1} \right )^2 \right ]_{z=0}$$

The value of the derivative term may be deduced from considering the sum:

$$\left ( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} z^k\right)^2 =  \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} z^k \sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1} z^{\ell} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1} z^{k+\ell} $$

The coefficient of $z^{n-1}$ in the above sum is the number of pairs $(k,\ell)$ that sum to $n-1$, or $n$.  Thus the value of the $(n-1)$th derivative at $z=0$ is $n (n-1)! = n!$.  Thus the value of the integral is

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} d\phi \frac{1-\cos{n \phi}}{1-\cos{\phi}} = 2 \pi n$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You now have the fraction 
$$
\frac{z^{-n}(z^n - 1)^2}{i(z-1)^2}
$$
Note, however, that $\frac{z^{n}-1}{z-1} = 1 + z + z^2 + \cdots z^{n-1}$.  Use this to simplify the above fraction to one without singularities on the unit disk.

**Second hint:** you now have
$$
\frac 1i \int_C \frac{(1 + z + z^2 + \cdots z^{n-1})^2}{z^n}
$$
By [Cauchy's integration formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem), we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac 1i \int_C \frac{(1 + z + z^2 + \cdots z^{n-1})^2}{z^n} &=
\frac{2 \pi }{(n-1)!} \left[\frac{(n-1)!}{2 \pi i} \int_C \frac{(1 + z + z^2 + \cdots z^{n-1})^2}{z^{(n-1)+1}}\right]\\
&= \frac{2 \pi }{(n-1)!} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left[(1 + z + z^2 + \cdots z^{n-1})^2\right]_{z=0}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I don't know, I obtain $\int_C \frac{1}{i} z^{-n} (1 + ... + z^{n-1})^2 dz$. I still don't obtain under integral $\frac{1}{z} f(z)$ where $f$ is a holomorphic function, which I would like to get to use a Cauchy formula.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  Is that clearer?

Comment: Oh whoops, never mind